# Writing to a .plist file

Tags: arrays, dictionary, save, plist

I have a .plist with 2 key values in it. It is of type Dictionary. I am trying to write value to one of the key values. What's wrong with the code below? I also tried using type "Array". That option also does not work. How can I get it to work using Dictionary & also Array? Anyone has working code example? Thanks. I would appreciate any help.

NSString *filePath = @"myprefs.plist";

NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

[plistDict setValue:@"test@test.com" forKey:@"Email"];

[plistDict writeToFile:filePath atomically: YES];

Answer (score 1):

You did not initialize the path properly.

If "myprefs.plist" is inside the resources folder of your project then initialize like this:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"myprefs" ofType:@"plist"];
```

If its somewhere else in your computer, specify the whole path